# Array turn to json using php

Tags: php, arrays, json, echo

need your help on this one...
I'm trying to create a code that will get a .txt file and convert all text content to json.

here's my sample code:

```
<?php

// make your required checks

$fp    = 'SampleMessage01.txt';

// get the contents of file in array
$conents_arr   = file($fp, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach($conents_arr as $key=>$value)
{
    $conents_arr[$key]  = rtrim($value, "\r");
}

$json_contents = json_encode($conents_arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

echo $json_contents;
?>
```

I already got the result when i tried to echo the `$json_contents`

```
["Sample Material 1","tRAINING|ENDING","01/25/2018 9:37:00 AM","639176882315,639176882859","Y,Y","~"]
```

but when I tried to echo using like this method `$json_contents[0]`
I only got per character result.

**Code**

[image]

**Result**

[image]

hope you can help me on this one..
thank you

Comment: Why are you echoing `[0]`? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**json_encode()** function takes an array as input and convert it to json string.

echo `$json_contents;` just print out the string.

if you want to access it you have to **decode** the JSON string to array.

```
//this convert array to json string
$json_contents = json_encode($conents_arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

//this convert json string to an array.
$json_contents = json_decode($json_contents, true);

//now you can access it 
echo $json_contents[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because `$json_contents` is a string. It might be json string but it's string so string properties will apply here and hence when you `echo $json_contents[0]` it gives you first character of the string. You can either decode the encoded json string to object like below:

```
$json = json_decode($json_contents);
echo $json[0];
```

or echo it before the `json_encode`:

```
echo $conents_arr[0];
$json_contents = json_encode($conents_arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Answer (score 1):

As PHP.net says
"Returns a **string** containing the JSON representation of the supplied value."

As you are using $json_contents[0] this will return the first char of the json string.

You can do this

```
$conents_arr[0]
```

Or convert your json string to PHP array using

```
$json_array = json_decode($json_contents, true);
echo $json_array[0];
```